# Updating excel macros with clickonce

Tags: excel, vba, clickonce

We have developed a complex excel workbook that has numerous tabs and lots of excel macros tied to various cells within the workbook.  We plan on distributing the workbook to users via clickonce from a common network share so we can push updates to the spreadsheets as necessary.

Once thing we have noticed is that it appears when we try to update the macros in the workbook that these are not updated via clickonce -- only the changes in individual tabs are made.  But the excel macros don't seem to get updated.

Is this expected behavior?  Are we doing something wrong with clickonce?  It seems like a critical flaw in the clickonce design if macros can't get updated.

Not sure how to proceed -- suggestions eagerly sought!

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: What kind of project are you doing to create this clickonce deployment? Is it VSTO? How are you updating the workbook inside of the clickonce project? It's not clear exactly what's happening here.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use a VSTO Add-in and develop everything in C#.  Far greater flexibility and control and when you publish the Add-in with changes, they automatically get pushed down.